# Is there a way to make a listbox in razor c# with items selected from a dropdownlist?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I have a drop down list of values and when the user selects an item it triggers an event listener. I want to allow the users to add multiple selections to a list (I do not want to just allow multi-select because the list can be pretty long)

```
    <div id="selectProps">
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.siteId, new SelectList(Model.listOfSites.Select(x => new
       {
           Value = x.SiteID,
           Text = x.SiteName
       }), "Value", "Text"), " ---Select a Property--- ", new { id = "ddlProperties", style = "max-width: 500px; width: 100%" })
    </div>
```

How can I add selections from this dropdown menu to a new list box ?

Comment: You'll need to use some javascript, I don't think this has anything to do with razor since it's dynamic on the client.

Comment: It would help significantly to see an example of your dropdown values, and how they would link together.